# fwrite cuts off character string

Tags: c, printf, fwrite

I am trying to output the statistics from my program into a file. I first create some empty strings, then amend them using sprintf, this is because I need to turn floats into chars. I then write them to a file. 
I sort of works, but the output .txt file only returns 4 digits of precision regardless what I specify in sprintf.

CODE:

```
   METRIC.RESP_TIME =(( (long int )(tval_after.tv_sec*1000000 + tval_after.tv_usec) - (long int )(tval_before.tv_sec*1000000 + tval_before.tv_usec)));
   METRIC.RESP_TIME = (float) METRIC.RESP_TIME/1000000;
   float ave_resp_time  = METRIC.RESP_TIME/R;
   float ave_through =  METRIC.BYTES_RECEIVED/METRIC.RESP_TIME;

   FILE *fp;
   char size_str [30];  //malloc(((int)strlen(DOWNLOAD_FILE)+ (int)strlen(Q[LOCAL_QUEUE_COUNT].CHORE_NAME)))];
   char rate_str [30];
   char through_put_str [30];

   sprintf(size_str,"TOTAL BYTES RECIEVED [B]: %5.0d  ", METRIC.BYTES_RECEIVED);
   sprintf(rate_str,"TOTAL TIME REQUIRED [s]: %2.8f  ", ave_resp_time);
   sprintf(through_put_str,"AVERAGE THROUGHPUT [B/s]: %2.8f ", ave_through);
   fprintf(stdout,"%d\n",METRIC.BYTES_RECEIVED);

   fp = fopen( METRICS_FILE, "w");
   if(NULL == fp){
   printf("Could not make metrics file: error %d ",errno);
      return 0;
   }
   fwrite(size_str,(size_t)sizeof(size_str),1,fp);       
   fwrite(rate_str,sizeof(rate_str),1,fp);
   fwrite(through_put_str,sizeof(through_put_str),1,fp);
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
```

OUTPUT:

```
     TOTAL BYTES RECIEVED [B]: 5526TOTAL TIME REQUIRED [s]: 0.001AVERAGE THROUGHPUT [B/s]: 2992
```

Hoping to make it look like:

```
   TOTAL BYTES RECIEVED [B]: 55264892 
   TOTAL TIME REQUIRED [s]: 0.0019634 
   AVERAGE THROUGHPUT [B/s]: 29929054
```

Comment: what do you think this `strcat(size_str,"\0");` does? `snprinf()` adds the terminating `nul` byte automatically.

Comment: The `fprintf` in iharob's answer should work. The problem is that `size_str` is only 30 bytes, but the `sprintf` puts 26 characters into `size_str` *before* it puts the number, so there are only 4 characters left for the number.

Comment: Am I missing the obvious, or is this code not using `fwrite()` at all?  _[...time passes...]_ Oh, I see: a recent edit devastated the code, replacing semi-plausible `sprintf()` statements with implausible `fprintf()` statements, and removing the `fwrite()` call referenced in the title.  Don't wreck your question after you've asked it.  _(I've rolled back the erroneous edit.)_

Comment: Your problem is created in part by not using `snprintf()`, and in part by trying to squeeze more than 30 characters into a 30-byte array.  Your string `size_str` is not big enough for the data you are trying to write into it.  This leads to undefined behaviour because you overflow your arrays.   The `%2.8f` string is weird; print 2 digits total, but 8 digits after the decimal point?  And I think this runs out of space too (but I like to let my computer do the counting).

Comment: @Claynux What is the type of `METRIC.BYTES_RECEIVED`?

Comment: @iharob The strcat(size_str, "\0"); was an attempt to insert a space at the end of the string in hopes that fwrite() would print up to that character. It didnt work as I mentioned previously.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  You're right you cant fit a 35 byte string in to a 30 byte one.... oh man thank you! I feel like an idiot, I remember thinking "30 thats plenty big" imagine my surprise when I counted. I still want the last few hours of my confused angry life back, hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

You need an explicit new line character; `fwrite()` does not add one, and also you can directly use `fprintf()` instead of what you have.

To fix your code, do this

```
sprintf(size_str, "TOTAL BYTES RECIEVED [B]: %5.0d\n", METRIC.BYTES_RECEIVED);
/*                                                 ^ this will break the line */
```

the `strcat(size_str, "\0");` is not needed.

You don't have to do all this, because you can just

```
fprintf(fp, "TOTAL BYTES RECIEVED [B]: %5.0d\n", METRIC.BYTES_RECEIVED);
/*                                           ^ this will break the line */
```

Comment: the  'strcat(size_str, "\0");' was a last ditch effort to get something working (didnt do anything).

Comment: Ahh! That cuts out a step, thank you, but the output is exactly the same :/

Comment: @Claynux Are you on windows? and how did you inspect the file? did you use notepad?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), use well sized buffers rather than hoping that `30` is ample.

One method that has worked well is to size the buffer per the `sprintf()`

```
// char size_str [30];
// sprintf(size_str,"TOTAL BYTES RECIEVED [B]: %5.0d  ", METRIC.BYTES_RECEIVED);

#define INT_MAX_PRT (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)
const char rcv_fmt[] = "TOTAL BYTES RECEIVED [B]: %5.0d\n";
char size_str [sizeof rcv_fmt + INT_MAX_PRT];
sprintf(size_str, rcv_fmt,  METRIC.BYTES_RECEIVED);
```

This approach is a bit more challenging with floating point as the `"%f"` width could be so large.

```
// char rate_str [30];
// sprintf(rate_str,"TOTAL TIME REQUIRED [s]: %2.8f  ", ave_resp_time);

#define FLT_MAX_PRT (1 /* sign */ + FLT_MAX_10_EXP + 1)
const char *time_fmt[] = "TOTAL TIME REQUIRED [s]: %2.8f\n";
char rate_str[sizeof time_fmt +  FLT_MAX_PRT + 8];
sprintf(rate_str, time_fmt, ave_resp_time);
```

Still, since it is possible to mistake the needed buffer size, code could also use `snprintf()` to minimize the harm.  But in the end, a proper size buffer is needed.

Note: added `'\n'` to the formats.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you should get out of the habit of using sizeof on any array. This will get you into trouble faster than you realize.

Second, you seem to be doing double-duty here. There is no need to use sprintf + fwrite at all. You should just fprintf and pass you fp as the first arg.

Comment: Used on arrays, `sizeof()` is invaluable; used on pointers masquerading as arrays (e.g. function parameters), it leads to problems.  But the problem is not being sure about the type of object you're sizing, not that `sizeof()` is bad.